# Is there a way to auto set the size of the text to fit a shape in visio using python?

Tags: python, winapi, visio, pywin32

I am trying to use Python to create shapes with text in Visio. I was wondering if there was a way to have the text size auto fit into the shape, instead of selecting a specific text size?

This is the code for setting the text to size 6pt.

```
shape.Cells( 'Char.size' ).FormulaU = '6 pt'
```

Comment: Did you try to set the text to fit a shape in Visio? Like [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-it-possible-for-visio-to-automatically-fit-text/64850a7d-e512-4cc7-b073-3b322df2f1d6).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!